# How to write webpage to cache?

Tags: android, caching, html

I want to load a webpage, and if it was already loaded before and not modified then load it from cache. If it is found to be modified, then clear this page in the cache and reload.

How can I do this?

1. Write the webpage into the cache
2. Find the webpage in the cache
3. Show the webpage from the cache
4. Clear the cache and load a new version if the page was modified

Please help me. It would be awesome if can show me the code for each of the above.
Best regards.

Comment: Do you want to do it programmically or just working on a browser while you are offline.

Comment: I want to do it programmically. And it will be working online. I want to load page from cache, if it did not modify. I use webview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using Webview then LOAD_NORMAL is for u.

webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NORMAL);
webView.loadUrl(HELPER.SERVER_BASE_LINK + "ads/s_image" + (i+1) + ".jpg");

It uses cache to load the webpage unless the page is modified, which is also mentioned in the description of setCacheMode();

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setCacheMode%28int%29

It takes a few minutes (within 5) to reload the modified page. It is probably the poling time of Android for checking expired pages. I have tried it myself, but I felt bugs in it, sometimes it just doesn't load the cache. It might be that android is taking my cache back too quickly, which is usually not the case.

Using cache with browsers will have some similar method.